# Leap motion android

Tags: android, leap-motion

I have gone through the Android SDK which leap motion has released.
Does anyone know as how to start with the same.
I want to create a basic android app using leapmotion which shows the hand in VR on android phone and can operate based on the hand.

With the examples that are available i am not able to see the hand.
Examples currently available require to create a server and leapmotion enters data to server and app reads from server. But Is it possible to see the whole hand.

Answer (score 0):

The Leap Motion API doesn't handle the graphics -- that part is up to you. Frequently, people use an engine like Unity and one of the VR APIs to help with managing the 3D visuals, etc. There are some examples using the Cardboard and the Durovis Dive APIs and Unity here: https://github.com/leapmotion-examples/LeapMotionWidgets/tree/cardboard-vr

Answer (score 0):

As previous post, in Unity there are sample hands already to be use on your project. If you are working with Native JAVA, this will be alot of work for you to create a hand on JAVA, no official samples so far from Leap Motion.

If controlling your phone with LM is your goal you can create a service running on background to check for gestures but if your goal is to do it from VR android API is very limited when it comes to VR. You cant start calls, or pickup them. As the VR app will go the background :(